# How do you make a regular expression that matches a word with one randomly inserted character?

Tags: javascript, regex, dojo

Hey all, i want to use a regular expression to match a word with one specified character randomly placed within it. I also want to keep that 'base' word's characters in their original order.

For example, with the 'base' word of `test` and the specified character of `'y'`, i want the regular expression to match all the following, and ONLY the following: `ytest, tyest, teyst, tesyt, testy`

Incase it matters, im working in javascript and using the dojo toolkit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be Regex? If not will this do?

```
function matches(testWord, baseWord)
{
    for (var i =0; i < testWord.length; i++)
    {
    if(testWord.substr(0,i) + testWord.substr(i+1,testWord.length- i) == baseWord)
        return true;
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: How silly of me... i was fixed on using regex's to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this with a single regular expression unless you're spelling it out explicitly - but `\b(ytest|tyest|teyst|tesyt|testy)\b` is probably not what you had in mind.

The next best regex-based solution would be to first match

```
\b(y)?t(y)?e(y)?s(y)?t(y)?\b
```

and then assert programmatically that only one of the five capturing groups actually matched something.

In the end, you're probably better off with a non-regex solution. Although I'd be glad to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In this one you can use a character class, like any number(/d) or some range of letters ([xyz]), if you pass the function a regexp for the third argument.

```
function matchPlus(string, base, plus){
    string= string.split(plus);
    return string.length== 2 && string.join('')== base;
}




//test case
var tA= 'ytest,tyest,teyst,test,ytesty,testyy,tesyt,testy'.split(','), L= 8;
while(L){
    tem= tA[--L];
    tA[L]= tem+'= '+!!matchPlus(tem,'test','y');
}

alert(testA.join('\n'))

/*  returned value: (String)
ytest= true
tyest= true
teyst= true
test= false
ytesty= false
testyy= false
tesyt= true
testy= true
*/
```